# in Javascript, how to create the new array using another array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The output that I want to have is newArray = [4, 9, 16, 25]. But I don't get it. Where did I make errors? Please help me.

```
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = [];

function multiply(a) {
   return a * a;
}

function newArray (a) {
    for (i=0; i<a.lenght; i++){
        result.push(multiply(a.value));
    }
}

var newArray = newArray(array);
```

Comment: `(a.value)` is not defined, just `result.push(multiply(a[i]));` .

Comment: `a.length` should be there. You misspelled it.

Comment: You also forget `return` the result.

Comment: Thank you for pinpointing the errors. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5];

function multiply(a) {
   return a * a;
}

function newArray (a) {
    return a.map(multiply)
}


var result = newArray(array); 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, but pushing the muliplied elements into the array, result is not done.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it

```js
const array = [2,3,4,5];

function multipliedArray(arr) {
  return arr.map(x => x * x);
}

console.log(multipliedArray(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your logic as it is.

You misspelled `a.length`.
And you missed the index with array `a`.

```
var array = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var result = [];

function multiply(a) {
   return a * a;
}

function newArray (a) {
    for (i=0; i<a.length; i++){ //spelling mistake
        result.push(multiply(a[i])); // index should be used
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(newArray(array));
```

Comment: I press the down arrow and it turned blue. This is the upvote, right?

Comment: Sorry, Hemal. I did not know how to upvote. I find I can not correct it once I have upvoted the other answer. I am very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I use ES6, I can change the codes like the following.

`const arrayPast = [2, 3, 4, 5];
const result = [];
const appendArray = arrayPast.map(x => x * x);
result.push(appendArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, using forEach

```
const oldArray = [3, 4, 5, 6];
const square = [];
const newArray = oldArray.forEach((x) => square.push(x * x));
```